# Codeigniter 2 Autocomplete from Database

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter-2

I am trying to set up an autocomplete input box on a form and although everything seems to work I an getting no data passed to the input box. Firebug reports a success but nothing there. I was wondering if some one could look at my code to see if there are any glaring errors that may be causing it.

Script is:

```
(function($){
    $("#town").autocomplete({
        source :"drivers/driver_gettown",
        minLength : 3,
        dataType:'JSON',
        type:'POST'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Input Box is:

```
   <div class="div">
        <input name="town" id="town"  type="text" class="txtSelect input required" value="<?php echo set_value('town'); ?>" />
        <?php echo form_error('town'); ?>
    </div>
```

Model is:

```
class Driver_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        // Load the Database
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }


    function driver_get_towns($q)
    {
        // Get a list of Towns
        // Search for row "place_name" from Table called "tbk_towns"
        $this->db->select('place_name');
        $this->db->like('place_name', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbk_towns');
        if($query->num_rows > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                //build an array for the towns
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(ucfirst($row['place_name'])); 
            }
            //format the array into json data
            // header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
            // echo json_encode($row_set);
            $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_output(json_encode($row_set)); 
        }
    }
}
```

and Finally the controller:

```
class Drivers extends CI_Controller 
{

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('driver_model');
        $this->load->helper('url', 'form', 'html', 'json');
    }

    function index()
    {
        // Just loads the main Page of the Drivers Area
        $data['metatitle'] = "Auto Ninja | Drivers Members Area | Locally Rated Garages &amp; Mechanics";
        $data['metadescription'] = "Garages &amp Mechanics";
        $data['metakeywords'] = "Car Repair, Car Service, Car MOT";
        $this->load->view('drivers/header_drivers.inc.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('drivers/index');
        $this->load->view('drivers/footer_index.inc.php');
    }


    public function driver_gettown()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['term'])){
            exit;
        }
        $this->load->model('driver_model');
        $q = ucfirst($_GET['term']);
        $this->driver_model->driver_get_towns($q);
    }

}
```

and comments/help would be gratefully appreciated.

```
function driver_addjob()
    {
        // Loads the Add New Job Form for the Website
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'session'));
        $this->load->model('driver_model');
        $this ->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');
        // Validate the form fields
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('town', 'Nearest Town or City', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        // Populates dropdown "town" from the database  ???

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)

        {
            $data['metatitle'] = "Auto Ninja | Drivers - Add New Job | Locally Rated Garages &amp; Mechanics";
            $data['metadescription'] = "Garages &amp Mechanics";
            $data['metakeywords'] = "Car Repair, Car Service, Car MOT";
            $this->load->view('drivers/header_drivers.inc.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('drivers/driver_addjob.php');
            $this->load->view('drivers/footer_index.inc.php');
        }
        else 
        {
            $townid = $this->input->post('town');
            $work_jobtitle = $this->input->post('jobtitle');
            $this->driver_model->driver_add_job ($townid);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'your work request has been added to the system');
            $data['metatitle'] = "Auto Ninja | Drivers - Add New Jobs Success | Locally Rated Garages &amp; Mechanics";
            $data['metadescription'] = "Garages &amp Mechanics";
            $data['metakeywords'] = "Car Repair, Car Service, Car MOT";
            $this->load->view('drivers/header_drivers.inc.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('drivers/driver_addjob_success');
            $this->load->view('drivers/footer_index.inc.php');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show what the response from Firebug looks like?

Comment: Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host php.codeigniter.server
Referer http://php.codeigniter.server/drivers/driver_addjob
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
200 OK 50ms

Comment: What I have noticed is that the header & footer  of the page only seem to be getting returned looking at the console window.

Comment: I think i need the result from the public function driver_gettown() to be added to the function driver_addjob() just under the validation rules but unsure just how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this one out. For some reason the response URL is coming out at
http://php.codeigniter.server/drivers/drivers/driver_gettown?term=ed

so the controller is being added twice. I updated the Java to

```
(function($){
    $("#town").autocomplete({
        source :"driver_gettown",
        minLength : 3,
        dataType:'JSON',
        type:'POST'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

ie not including the controller and it works!!! So a tad confused as to how it knows which controller to find the method in but who cares it works. It would be nice to know though as it will probably still annoy me... Possibly the JSON call bring it over in the URL maby?